# Inner join query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

code:

```
public function draft_post($idd)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('registration');
    $this->db->join('draft_registration', 'registration.user_id= draft_registration.user_id','INNER');
    $this->db->where('registration.user_id', $idd);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In this codes, I have two table i.e. `registration and draft_registration`. Now, What am I doing here I want to run inner join in Codeigniter. Now, What happening when I hit this query on `phpmyadmin` it shows wrong data i.e. I have two rows in `draft_registration` and one row in `registration` table but it always shows two table which is wrong and my query looks like when I was print as mention below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `registration`
INNER JOIN `draft_registration` ON `registration`.`user_id`= `draft_registration`.`user_id`
WHERE `registration`.`user_id` = '20181121064044'
```

So, How can I resolve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: There is a good chance that the query isn't wrong.
it is showing two result rows because the joining field (user_id) has two rows in one of your tables.  If you want to get one result row  look at the differences between the two rows and add a filter to draft_registration or registration.
Otherwise if it doesn't matter, either limit the result to 1, or just get the first_row()

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*'); //This code get all rows from both table.If you want a particular row you mention the column name.

For example:
$this->db->select('registration.name,draft_registration.city,draft_registration.state');
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify column that you want to select. Or if you want select all column of your table, you can use :

`SELECT registration.*` with backticks `` on column name

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code

```
public function draft_post($idd)
{
$this->db->select('registration.*,draft_registration.*');
$this->db->from('registration');
$this->db->join('draft_registration', 'registration.user_id= draft_registration.user_id');
$this->db->where('registration.user_id', $idd);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

Or you can use with objects

```
public function draft_post($idd)
{
$this->db->select('a.*,b.*');
$this->db->from('registration a');
$this->db->join('draft_registration b', 'a.user_id= b.user_id');
$this->db->where('a.user_id', $idd);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
}
```